# setState does not trigger update - reactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with socket.io and react. I set up the listener in componentDidMount() and somehow the setState() function does not trigger the update. When i log the `data`, i can see the data sent from server. Here is my code:

```
this.state = {
    list: []
};

public componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io('https://mybackendurl.com');
    this.socket.on('an-event', data => {
      console.log(data);
      const list = [...this.state.list];

      const updatedItemIndex = list.findIndex(
        d => d.id === data.id
      ) as number;
      list[updatedItemIndex].approvedBy = data.approvedBy;
      this.setState({ list });
    });
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem and how can solve this?

Comment: try removing the public keyword

Comment: I would recommend putting your ```socket.on``` function in a separate file, not super necessary but it's how I do it.  Then I would call ```socket.emit``` within componentDidMount and setState with the result that you get back.

Comment: If you console log right before you call `setState` do you see your updated array?

Comment: @BrianThompson yes i can see my updated array. I can see that my state is updated too. But the DOM is not updated

Comment: @KhanhLuu, are you using PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate or useMemo? for the data which is changing?

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentDidMount` triggers once after the component loaded. You need to use `componentDidUpdate()`
And you should check 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with full confidence that this would cause react to not see the state diff, but you are technically mutating state, which may cause react to see the old mutated state as matching the new updated state and choose not to re-render. 
You do `const list = [...this.state.list]` to create a new list array which is good, but the nested object that you update will still be the previous reference. Try creating a new nested object as well.

```js
this.socket.on('an-event', data => {
  const list = [...this.state.list.map(item => ({...item})]; // create new object 

  const updatedItemIndex = list.findIndex(
    d => d.id === data.id
  ) as number;
  list[updatedItemIndex].approvedBy = data.approvedBy;
  this.setState({ list });
});
```